# why isn't my python code using all of the cpu?

Tags: python, linux, windows, cpu

i wrote a simple python code that just prints prime numbers nonstop but it only uses 25% percent of my laptops cpu (100% of a single core) .
but i want it to use all of the cores. is that possible?
BTW here is the code:

```python
x = 10
while True:
    for num in range(1, x):
        flag = False
        if x > 1:
            for i in range(2, x):
                if (x % i) == 0:
                    flag = True
                    break
        if not flag:
            print(x, "is a prime number")
            break
    x += 1
```

Comment: You are using a single thread software. It can only utilize 100% for a single core on your system.

Comment: It happily eats 100% of 1 core (CPU) on my machine.

Comment: I initially tried with macOS, and now in a Linux VM. Same result: eats 100% of 1 CPU.

Comment: This algorithm is fairly easily parallelizable: just split the range `(1..x)` is parts, with each core checking a subrange. But it's not that easy in Python.

Comment: @MSalters It's not like it's very difficult either, but it doesn't make much sense to try and parallelize such a naive algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

This begs the question: how did you measure how much CPU your program uses?

Here's a screenshot from my macOS machine, running your program:

[image]

And here, a screenshot from `htop` on a Linux virtual machine:

[image]

In other words, your program will happily consume as much of a *single CPU core* as it can, as it's single-threaded.

## EDIT

To make your program consume all of your cores with plain Python, just threads won't unfortunately cut it due to the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://realpython.com/python-gil/) making Python-based parallel CPU work quite inefficient.

Happily, that's where the `multiprocessing` module steps in; it orchestrates multiple separate Python *processes* that aren't encumbered by a shared lock.  You can see that this program is already quite a bit more complex, but does manage to saturate all 16 cores on my machine.

[image]

Since the workers look at different parts of the integer range, the results printed by this program won't be in strict order at all.

```
import multiprocessing
import queue
from itertools import count


def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(2, x // 2 + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def prime_loop(result_queue: multiprocessing.Queue, start: int, step: int):
    for i in count(start, step):
        if is_prime(i):
            result_queue.put((i, True))


def main():
    result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    num_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    workers = []
    for i in range(num_workers):
        # Since there's no point in starting a worker that would look at even numbers,
        # we start the first worker at 1 and the second worker at 3, etc.
        start = i * 2 + 1
        # Each worker will step over by the number of workers + 1, so e.g. if there are 4 workers,
        # worker 1 will check 1, 5, 11, 16,
        # worker 2 will check 2, 6, 12, 17,
        # worker 3 will check 3, 7, 13, 18,
        # worker 4 will check 4, 8, 14, 19 etc.
        step = num_workers + 1
        worker = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=prime_loop, args=(result_queue, start, step)
        )
        worker.start()
        workers.append(worker)
    seen = set()
    while True:
        try:
            number, result = result_queue.get(timeout=0.1)
            if result:
                if number in seen:
                    raise NotImplementedError("bug :(")
                seen.add(number)
                print(f"{number} is a prime number")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        except (multiprocessing.TimeoutError, queue.Empty):
            pass
    for worker in workers:
        worker.kill()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: yes i just edited my question i asked it wrong it uses 100% of a single core but can i make it multi-threaded.(as its obvious i'm new to programing)

Comment: Sure. See my edit, please.